# Java automatic return type covariance with generic subclassing

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, subclass, covariance

I have two interfaces that look like this:

```
interface Parent<T extends Number> {
    T foo();
}

interface Child<T extends Integer> extends Parent<T> {
}
```

If I have a raw `Parent` object, calling `foo()` defaults to returning a `Number` since there is no type parameter.

```
Parent parent = getRawParent();
Number result = parent.foo(); // the compiler knows this returns a Number
```

This makes sense.

If I have a raw `Child` object, I would expect that calling `foo()` would return an `Integer` by the same logic. However, the compiler claims that it returns a `Number`.

```
Child child = getRawChild();
Integer result = child.foo(); // compiler error; foo() returns a Number, not an Integer
```

I can override `Parent.foo()` in `Child` to fix this, like so:

```
interface Child<T extends Integer> extends Parent<T> {
    @Override
    T foo(); // compiler would now default to returning an Integer
}
```

Why does this happen? Is there a way to have `Child.foo()` default to returning an `Integer` without overriding `Parent.foo()`?

EDIT: Pretend `Integer` isn't final. I just picked `Number` and `Integer` as examples, but obviously they weren't the best choice. :S

Comment: I think it's because without the child's override, the child inherits the parent's `foo` method, and, according to the parent, `T` is a `Number`. For `foo` in the parent to return an `Integer`, it would need to know information about its child class(es), which kind of breaks the hierarchy...

Comment: try `interface Child<T extends Integer> extends Parent<T extends Integer>`

Comment: @fukanchik that isn't even valid Java.

Comment: @AdamGent thanks you are right it fails to compile. I looked through JLS `Chapter 4. Types, Values, and Variables ` and couldn't find the exact point where it says upper bound is not allowed here.

Comment: @fukanchik It's a [type argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. This is based on ideas of @AdamGent .
2. Unfortunately I am not fluent with JLS enough to prove the below from the spec.

Imagine `public interface Parent<T extends Number>` was defined in a **different compilation unit** - in a separate file `Parent.java`.

Then, when compiling `Child` and `main`, the compiler would see method `foo` as `Number foo()`. Proof:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
interface Parent<T extends Number> {
    T foo();
}

interface Child<R extends Integer> extends Parent<R> {
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Child.class.getMethod("foo").getReturnType());
    }
}
```

prints:

```
class java.lang.Number
```

This output is reasonable as java does type erasure and is not able to retain `T extends` in the result `.class` file *plus* because method `foo()` is only defined in `Parent`. To change the result type in the child compiler would need to insert a *stub* `Integer foo()` method into the `Child.class` bytecode. This is because there remains no information about generic types after compilation.

Now if you modify your child to be:

```
interface Child<R extends Integer> extends Parent<R> {
    @Override R foo();
}
```

e.g. add own `foo()` into the `Child` the compiler will create `Child`'s own copy of the method in the `.class` file with a different but still compatible prototype `Integer foo()`. Now output is:

```
class java.lang.Integer
```

This is confusing of course, because people would expect "lexical visibility" instead of "bytecode visibility".

Alternative is when compiler would compile this *differently* in two cases: interface in the same "lexical scope" where compiler can see source code and interface in a different compilation unit when compiler can only see bytecode. I don't think this is a good alternative.

Comment: I deleted my answer in favor of yours. I'm not sure why mine was getting down voted (probably because I was confused in thinking the OP wanted to know why Java chose to implement generics the way that it does). It would have been helpful had the downvoter just added a comment. But your answer and @Scottb are better.

Answer (score 1):

The `T`s aren't exactly the same.  Imagine that the interfaces were defined like this instead:

```
interface Parent<T1 extends Number> {
    T1 foo();
}

interface Child<T2 extends Integer> extends Parent<T2> {
}
```

The `Child` interface extends the `Parent` interface, so we can "substitute" the formal type parameter T1 with the "actual" type parameter which we can say is `"T2 extends Integer"`:

```
interface Parent<<T2 extends Integer> extends Number>
```

this is only allowed because Integer is a subtype of Number.  Therefore, the signature of `foo()` in the `Parent` interface (after being extended in the `Child` interface) is simplified to:

```
interface Parent<T2 extends Number> {
    T2 foo();
}
```

In other words, the signature is not changed.  The method `foo()` as declared in the `Parent` interface continues to return `Number` as the raw type.

Comment: The signature doesn't change but there are languages that will do generic expansion (that is it will copy/create methods in subclasses). It has to do how Java implemented generics.

Comment: There are definitely some peculiarities in the way that generic types are implemented in the Java language (Java is not unique in this), but it is usually possible to anticipate and work with these.

Comment: I agree but I can understand the OPs confusion.